# How to search / filter ContentItems collection in Taxonomy term

Tags: orchardcms

I have a taxonomy called `Products` that has a collection of my custom content type `Range` associated with it. `Range` also has a taxonomy field to select which sub category it is in (similar to Tags I suppose).

When I navigate to a term in my `Products` taxonomy (e.g. 'Keyboards'), Orchard automatically returns all associated `Range` items associated with it in the ContentItems, which is great.

However, I need the user to be able to filter the collection of `Range` items based on the sub category (e.g. Wireless, Bluetooth, etc), but I am struggling to understand how I would implement it.

Everything is displaying exactly how I want it, I just can't work out how to filter the items based on user selection. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the taxonomyService? I think the GetContentItems-Method should work for you. You would pass in your term and an optional field name and it returns an IEnumerable<IContent>.